# Creating a large body of text with different styles - JavaFX FXML

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

In the fxml class of my JavaFx application I want to add a large body of text using minimal components (instead of adding multiple labels per line). I would also like to create varying styles of text in the same component. What component should I use (e.g TextArea) and how would I go about create multiple styles inside it (using css).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [TextFlow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) and add [Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) to it. You can style individual Text component with different style using css on them.

**Complete example :**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFlowExample extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Text text1 = new Text("First Text\n");
        text1.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20; -fx-fill: darkred;");
        Text text2 = new Text("\nSecond Text");
        text2.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 30; -fx-fill: goldenrod;");
        TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow(text1, text2);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(textFlow, 200, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Equivalent FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>


<TextFlow lineSpacing="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" textAlignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-size: 20; -fx-fill: darkred;" text="&#10;&#10;First Text" />
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-size: 30; -fx-fill: goldenrod;" text="&#10;&#10;Second Text" />
   </children>
</TextFlow>
```

Comment: I found this quite a useful tutorial on TextFlow - https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Rich+Text+API+Samples

Comment: but "-fx-text-fill: color;" and "-fx-fill: color;" isn't changing the text color

Comment: I have added an example for more clarity :)

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason line break (\n) isn't working. It just appends "\n"

Comment: I guess you are trying it in fxml. I have added a FXML example as well.

Comment: Is it possible to add more Text Nodes after creation of the TextFlow?

Comment: @Baxtex Of course ;) You can use `getChildren()` on the TextFlow to add new Text nodes.