# Add a Bold button for the writing style without using HTMLEditor

Tags: javafx, togglebutton, bold

I currently have a TextArea, on which I would like to apply text to Bold when I press the ToggleButton Bold.
I saw that in Java SWING it is possible to use StyledEditorKit.BoldAction ().
Is there an equivalent in JavaFX?
Or do I have to code the method myself?

I do not want to use HTMLEditor, because I do not need the other buttons and I would like to apply it to several TextArea.

Thanks !

Comment: If you want to change the font for the whole TextArea, just do it :) If you want to change the font for certain parts of the text, that's not supported in TextArea.

Comment: @kleopatra Ah ok... Or I should use HTML content ?

Comment: You can use HTML, and show it in a Webview which can acts like a TextArea.

Comment: Maybe this _Stack Overflow_ question will help you? (Assuming you haven't already seen it.) [Creating a large body of text with different styles - JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974765/creating-a-large-body-of-text-with-different-styles-javafx-fxml)

Comment: I will use WebView I think.. Thanks everybody !